# Adding Objects to Security Group (PowerShell)

Tags: powershell, active-directory, automation, windows-server-2012-r2

So I have looked everywhere online, including here and something that should work, doesn't and I am out of ideas.  I want to add all AD Objects from one OU to a specific security group.  This is what I have (and from reading online, should work):

```
$ADObjects = "OU.Containing.AD.Objects"
$AddGroup = "DN.of.group.adding.objects.to"

 Get-ADComputer -SearchBase $ADObjects  -Filter * | ForEach-Object{Add-ADGroupMember -Identity 'Corporate Office Computers' -Members $_ -WhatIf}
```

When I run this, all the WhatIf messages appear and no errors show however once completed, none of the items from the $ADObjects OU are added.  Any suggestions?

Comment: (?) `-WhatIf` means "tell me what will happen without actually doing anything." When things look correct, you have to remove `-WhatIf`.

Comment: If you need an output of what is going on, you should use `-Verbose` instead of `-WhatIf`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might not understand the "WhatIf" switch. This will prevent any changes actually being actioned and will report "What if" would happen if the switch was not there. The following code worked on my system:

```
$ADObjects = "OU=Desktops,DC=MyDomain,DC=com"
$AddGroup = "GroupAddingObjectsTo"
Get-ADComputer -SearchBase $ADObjects  -Filter * | ForEach-Object {Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $AddGroup -Members $_}
```

Comment: Thank you guys for clearing that up! Problem solved!